# How can I make a embeded form responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

How do I make the following code responsive? Have been trying for the last few hours - in vain!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<title>OTM - India's Largest Travel Trade Show</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.otm.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/favicon.ico"/>


<body>

    <div class="intrinsic-container">
    <script>(function(e,t,c,n){var s,o,r;e.SMCX=e.SMCX||[],t.getElementById(n)||(s=t.getElementsByTagName(c),o=s[s.length-1],r=t.createElement(c),r.type="text/javascript",r.async=!0,r.id=n,r.src=["https:"===location.protocol?"https://":"http://","widget.surveymonkey.com/collect/website/js/7aGSqSw00rqyg6Tw_2FjuHxh37Sf45yyW7_2FNS7SGUQYwzciy8z1YFrcHGeEshrny3k.js"].join(""),o.parentNode.insertBefore(r,o))})(window,document,"script","smcx-sdk");</script><center><a style="font: 12px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;" target="blank" href=http://otm.co.in/>OTM - India's Largest Travel Trade Show</a></body></center>


   </div>
    <style type="text/css">

    html        {height:100%;}
    body { 
    background-color: #c5302e;
    height:100%;   
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .smcx-embed {
    width: 80% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    margin:0 auto  !important;
    background:#c5302e !important;
    }
    .smcx-iframe-container {

    width: 100% !important;
    position: relative !important;
    }
    .smcx-iframe-container iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%;}

    </style>


</html>
```

Comment: Please visit http://forms.otm.co.in for seeing the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with css, you should have access to the parent page and use a plugin: http://npr.github.io/responsiveiframe/